# Unable to create Image Slider web part using slideShow.js

Tags: 2013, javascript, css, visual-web-part

I want to make the web part for image sliding for Picture Library.

I got [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh920769%28v=vs.85%29.ASPX) link for doing so.

My code for visual web part is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>Slide Show</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .size {
            height: 300px;
            width: 500px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .lab {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            color: #FF0000;
            height: 80px;
            line-height: 20px;
            margin-top: 200px;
            padding: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 480px;
            z-index: 100;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="main" runat="server">

        <div id="slideShowImages" runat="server">

        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="../_layouts/15/JSLink/slideShow.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And background C# code is:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string HtmlCode = "";

        SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;

        SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;

        SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Pics");

        foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
        {
            HtmlCode += "<img src=" + Convert.ToString(item[SPBuiltInFieldId.EncodedAbsUrl]) + " alt='Image' class='size'/>";                
        }

        main.InnerHtml = "<Label>Hello</Label>";
        slideShowImages.InnerHtml = HtmlCode;
    }
```

The images are stored in picture library and the lable text will be fixed which is going to be float over the image.

I tried the code shown in msdn example working perfectly but when I apply this in Visual Web Part I am not able to do it as the ID of DIVs are changed when they are runat server.

What should I do to get the `html` output in my web part?

Comment: Remove `..` from `<script src="../_layouts/15/JSLink/slideShow.js"></script>`

Comment: The js is loaded successfully but the problem resides in the DIV id conflicts, i.e. in js the DIV id which has value `slideShowImages` are slide but when I apply the `runat` property the child DIV is not created (Here, `<div id="slideShowImages" runat="server">` in my case)

Comment: And also the ID of main DIV is also changed to `ctl00_ctl33_g_ee3e11ee_5274_4fcc_9b8d_c8eb66e2e682_main`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add `runat="server"` to a div tag it gets an auto generated id.

So when you in javascript or jQuery wants to get an element by ID and that element has the `runat="server"` attribute, then you need to use inline code to get it.

Example without runat="server" attribute

```
[HTML]
<div id="MyDIV">some content </div>

[jQuery]
var mydiv = $("#MyDIV");
```

Example with runat="server" attribute

```
[HTML]
<div id="MyDIV" runat="server">some content </div>

[jQuery]
var mydiv = $("#<%= MyDIV.CliendID%>");
```